# declaração if - uso de parenteses

Tags: python

O uso do parenteses com o if, altera performance do código ou modifica alguma coisa?

Exemplo, este:

`if (1 != 2):
    print('É True')`

em comparação com:

`if 1 != 2:
    print('É True')`

Caso seja apenas estético, qual forma é mais recorrente de se usar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O uso de parênteses, em especial para `if`e`while`, em Python, é mais uma decisão de [engenharia de software](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engenharia_de_software) e [manutenibilidade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manutenibilidade), não tendo esta qualquer relação com a performance de execução. <sup>[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4740444/10707951)</sup>

Princípios de código limpo, claro e correto, importantes para a [qualidade de software](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualidade_de_software), são afetados por esta decisão.

**Portanto, você deve utilizar parênteses quando estes ajudarão na leitura e entendimento do código**. <sup>[5](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201175/should-i-use-parentheses-in-logical-statements-even-where-not-necessary)</sup>

Um ponto aqui destacável é dizer sobre a [precedência de operadores](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), e nestes casos, o programador deve/necessita utilizar os parênteses para controle da ordem de execução das avaliações.

Como:

```
print(1 + 1 * 2, (1 + 1) * 2)  # print 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Não há nenhum ganho ou perda no uso de parênteses extras em expressões como `if` e `while`. Eles não são obrigatórios na linguagem justamente para simplificar a leitura das expressões. o `:` no final dos comandos faz a separação da expressão para o bloco contido no comando - portanto não existe a ambiguidade potencial que existe em `C` e as linguagens que copiaram a sua sintaxe exigindo o parênteses no `if`.

Parenteses extras são automaticamente elimnados no estágio de compilação do programa (lembrando que a compilação em Python é automática). Veja como uma função que usa parênteses e outra que não são idênticas depois de compiladas:

```
In [15]: def a():
    ...:     if qualquer_coisa == 1:
    ...:         pass
    ...:     

In [16]: def b():
    ...:     if (qualquer_coisa == 1):
    ...:         pass
    ...:     

In [17]: import dis

In [18]: dis.dis(a)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (qualquer_coisa)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              4 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8

  3     >>    8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

In [19]: dis.dis(b)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (qualquer_coisa)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              4 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8

  3     >>    8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Ou seja- o parênteses sequer está indicado no bytecode, que é o que é executado de fato - o processo de "descompilação" do `dis.dis` não tem nem como saber que ele existia no código fonte.

Note que isso não impede que você use parênteses para *melhorar* a legibilidade do código, sobretudo em expressões complexas de um `if` que podem ter que ser quebradas em mais de uma linha. Nesses casos, inclusive, os parênteses são preferíveis ao indicador de continuação de linha `\` .